# ¿Cómo habilitar/deshabiltar los checkbox en orden del primero al último?

Tags: javascript

Tengo por ejemplo estos 5 checkboxs a los cuales quiero en un principio que todos aparezcan deshabilitados (a excepción del primero). Luego al tildar el primero, necesito que se habilite el segundo. Si tildo el segundo que se habilite el tercero y así sucesivamente.

Pero si destildo el primero, que se destilden e inhabiliten todos los demás. Si tengo por ejemplo tres tildados y destildo el segundo, entonces que se destilde e inhabilite el tercero y así sucesivamente.

Lo que he logrado hacer solo funciona con el primero y el segundo check, necesito orientación para propagarlo a los demás.

Prueben marcando y desmarcando los 2 primeros checks del ejemplo que coloque.

```js
let checks = document.getElementsByName("option");

for (let index = 0; index < checks.length; index++) {
  if (index == 0) {
    checks[index].disabled = false;
    checks[index].addEventListener("change", function(){
      if (this.checked) {
        console.log("habilitar el siguiente check");
        checks[index+1].disabled = false;
      }else{
        console.log("inhabilitar y destildar el siguiente check");
        checks[index+1].disabled = true;
      }
    });
    continue;
  }
  checks[index].disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="option">1</input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option">2</input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option">3</input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option">4</input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option">5</input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu principal problema está en usar un `for` para los 2 casos (habilitar y deshabilitar), cuando solo el último lo requiere

Te dejo un ejemplo con comentarios

```js
//seleccionamos los input y los guardamos en un array
const inputs= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"));

//agregamos el evento a todos los inputs
inputs.forEach(a=>a.addEventListener("change", selection));

function selection(ev){
  let orden = inputs.indexOf(ev.target);
  if(orden+1>=inputs.length) return; //si es el últimno no hacemos nada

  //si es está checked habilitamos el siguiente
  if(ev.target.checked){
    inputs[orden+1].disabled=false;
  }
  else{ //caso contrarios deshabilitados todos los anteriores
     for(let i=orden+1; i<inputs.length; i++){
        inputs[i].disabled = true;
        inputs[i].checked  = false;
     }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  name="option">1</input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox"  name="option" disabled>2</input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox"  name="option" disabled>3</input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" disabled>4</input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" disabled>5</input>
```

Comment: Mil gracias Yussef, eso quedo maravilloso

Comment: @JGuerreroS Me alegro te haya servidor, recuerda marcar la respuesta aceptada si así te parece.

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un ejemplo programado en un estilo más tradicional que complementa a la respuesta anterior. No es muy distinto a lo que tenés hecho.
Te faltaba agregar un ciclo para deshabilitar el resto de los checks.

```js
    let checks = document.getElementsByName("option");
    for (let index = 0; index < checks.length; index++) {
      if (index < checks.length-1){
        checks[index].addEventListener("change", function(){
          if (this.checked) {
            checks[index+1].disabled = false;
          }else{
            for(let j=index; j < checks.length-1; j++){
              checks[j+1].checked = false;
              checks[j+1].disabled = true;
            }
          }
        });
      }
      checks[index].disabled = true;
    }   
    checks[0].disabled = false;
```

Comment: Gracias GavilanPatagonico, esta joya también

Comment: Si le agrego un console.log dentro del if (this.checked) { console.log("tildado") }; No me detecta el ultimo checkbox. Intente cambiando la condición del for, pero nada

Comment: Mirá bien el algoritmo... el último checkbox no tiene evento. Podrías hacer que tenga evento pero vas a tener que programar que si es el último que no haga nada (como en la otra respuesta).